# how do I write a proper query in kdb this case?

Tags: kdb

I would like to get all the groups that have a distinct price of 0 from my table, IE only if all prices are 0 in that group should it be returned.

My query & table look something like this.

```
tab:([]grp:`a`b`c`c`a`a`a;price:0 20 0 1 0 0 0)
select grp from tab where distinct price = 0
```

The output should only be `` `a `` since `` `a `` is the only group where all prices are 0.

Comment: Can you add a sample input / output? It's difficult to understand exactly what you want from your initial description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an `fby` is one way to achieve the result here.

```
q)tab:([]grp:`a`b`c`c`a`a`a;price:0 20 0 1 0 0 0)
q)select from tab where 0=(max;abs price)fby grp
grp price
---------
a   0
a   0
a   0
a   0
q)distinct exec grp from tab where 0=(max;abs price)fby grp
,`a
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach:

```
q)where exec all 0=price by grp from tab
,`a
```